# fn call doesnt execute on compile time

Tags: clojure

I have defined the following in one ns -

There is a services atom, and another function to add to that atom -

```
(ns ex.first)

(def services (atom []))

(defn add-service
  [fns]
  (swap! services conj fns))
```

In my code in another ns I do this -

```
(ns ex.second ..)

(add-service [fn1 fn2 fn3])
```

1) I am assuming that when I run my repl, which compiles the code, it should add the vector to the atom. However when I eval the `@services` it returns `[]`.

2) The above works if I eval the `(add-service [fn1 fn2 fn3])` in the repl.

3) I have also tried using converting the `add-service` fn to a macro. However still I find the `@services` to be empty.

So will appreciate if someone can help on these -

1) Why doesnt the add-service call add a vector to the atom on code compilation when -

- `add-service` is defined as a `fn`.
- `add-service` is defined as a `macro`.

2) How do I make it work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on if you have set `:aot` to `:all` in project.clj or not.

If `:aot` is `:all` then the function call will execute as soon as repl is started, otherwise you will need to load the `ex.second` namespace (ex: using `use`). Loading will cause the ns to be compiled and the corresponding class to be loaded in jvm and the function call will get executed.

Also, the function call doesn't happen at the **compile time**, it happens when the compiled class (representing the namespace) is loaded by jvm.

**UPDATED (based on comment):**

If you make it a macro, then also you need to consider the aot thing.

If aot is set to compile the namespace then lein will create a  jvm, load your code in it, call clojure compiler, which will read the code, execute the macro and compiles the code, at this time this jvm (which is used for compiling your code) will have `services` atom filled coz of macro execution, but this jvm was only for compilation. lein will then create another jvm for the run command and load the compiled class in that jvm but this jvm won't have the `services` filled in coz the classes doesn't have any code that fill it in.

If aot is not set then macro will work because the read,macroexpand,compile process will happen in the lein *run* jvm but only when you cause loading of the ns.

As far as "without loading the ns" is concern, what you can do is put the `ex.second` in the `:aot` of project.clj

Comment: thanks @Ankur that was very helpful. So there is no difference in terms of usage if I use a macro or fn. (Yes a macro will do it on compile time vs on load time in JVM) For both to work I still have to :use the ns. Is there a better pattern than just requiring ns or is :aot the option to go for? Also does the core ns get compiled by default ?

Comment: I have given all the upvotes I could. Thats a very detailed answer, thanks. So is the core.clj always compiled and loaded in jvm by default ? Also what does lein repl do, does it also just compile and load the core in the jvm ?

Comment: lein repl will start a JVM (using java command), setting classpath based on project.clj (this JVM will have clojure jar in classpath which is specified in your project.clj, lein has its own clojure jar). If the clojure.jar that you are refering in your project is aot compiled then core.clj is already compiled otherwise it is compiled on the load of ns. Clojure.jar is precompiled by the way, hence core.clj is already in compiled form.

Comment: Nope I am referring to the core.clj of my project (ns ex.core). The reason I am asking this is bcoz if I require the (ex.first) in my core, I see the fn call is made. So does it mean the ex.core ns of any project is automatically loaded and compiled ?

Comment: If you have `:main` in project.clj set to your core ns then the repl will start in this ns and hence loading the core ns